# Why does <right-click>Properties for an epub file cause the file manager (Caja) to crash?

Tags: file-management, epub, caja

**Environment:**

```
Ubuntu MATE 20.04
Linux 5.4.0-153-generic
#170-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 16 13:43:31 UTC 2023 
x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I've created a script [see script 1] which bundles up an EPUB file.

When I do a right-click on the resulting file, to get the context-menu, then select "**Preferences**" from the menu, **Caja** crashes !!!

[image]

At the command line, the "**file**" command reports OK as an epub file:

```
/DB001_F4/STACKS__Library$ file 'BOOK__SciFi__IAsimov__RDaneelOlivaw 2 - The Naked Sun__1956_1.epub'
BOOK__SciFi__IAsimov__RDaneelOlivaw 2 - The Naked Sun__1956_1.epub: EPUB document
/DB001_F4/STACKS__Library$
```

Also from the command line, the **einfo** command seems to report no issue:

```
/DB001_F4/STACKS__Library$ einfo 'BOOK__SciFi__IAsimov__RDaneelOlivaw 2 - The Naked Sun__1956_u.epub'
Filename:    BOOK__SciFi__IAsimov__RDaneelOlivaw 2 - The Naked Sun__1956_u.epub
Root(s):
   OEBPS/content.opf (application/oebps-package+xml)
Title(s):
   The Naked Sun
Creator(s):
   aut: Isaac Asimov (Asimov, Isaac)
Identifier(s):
   5c1396b5-6ede-5b81-87d6-dec6d1b2867a(uuid:uuid_id)
9780553293395(ISBN:unspecified)
Reading order:
   COVERpage(L) DUSTJACKETBLURBpage(L) STORYSUMMARYpage(L) ABOUTAUTHORpage(L) TITLEpage(L) COPYRIGHTSpage(L) DEDICATIONpage(L) TOCpage(L) chpt-001(L) chpt-002(L) chpt-003(L) chpt-004(L) chpt-005(L) chpt-006(L) chpt-007(L) chpt-008(L) chpt-009(L) chpt-010(L) chpt-011(L) chpt-012(L) chpt-013(L) chpt-014(L) chpt-015(L) chpt-016(L) chpt-017(L) 
Guide:
   Cover -> Text/binder_001_COVER.html(cover)
Extra local metadata:
   cover : cover
unspecified : unspecified
unspecified : unspecified
/DB001_F4/STACKS__Library$
```

Please note that the script creates **both acceptable format-types** for EPUB:

1. no files compressed
2. only "mimetype" not compressed

Note also, that mimetype is the **first file archived** in both zip files.

Lastly, I can open both files for viewing with the calibre-supplied EPUB viewer without any problems.

Can anyone explain why?

**Beginning of the content.opf file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" version="2.0" unique-identifier="uuid_id">

  <metadata
    xmlns:opf="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:calibre="http://calibre.kovidgoyal.net/2009/metadata">
    <!-- insert point for other considerations -->
    <meta name="cover" content="cover"/>
    <dc:date>2023-08-06T22:09:52-04:00</dc:date>
    <dc:language>en_CA</dc:language>
    <dc:identifier id="uuid_id" opf:scheme="uuid">5c1396b5-6ede-5b81-87d6-dec6d1b2867a</dc:identifier>
    <dc:identifier opf:scheme="ISBN">9780553293395</dc:identifier>
    <dc:title id="title">The Naked Sun</dc:title>
    <dc:creator opf:role="aut" opf:file-as="Asimov, Isaac">Isaac Asimov</dc:creator>
    <dc:publisher>Fawcett Publications, Inc. / Greenwich, Conn.</dc:publisher>
    <dc:subject id="subject-1">Science fiction</dc:subject>
    <meta property="authority" refines="#subject-1">LCSH</meta>
    <meta property="term" refines="#subject-1">sh85118629</meta>
    <dc:description>THE PLANET SOLARIA
```

COULD DESTROY EARTH
IN TWO SECONDS FLAT

And probably would ... eventually.

Solaria was powerful and power-hungry.  It had taken over two hundred years ot develop the ultimate weapon ... a massive army of robots that could obliterate Earth and rule the universe in a matter of days.

But now that would have to wait.

One of Solaria's most eminent scientists has suddenly been found brutally murdered.  Only Earth's most famous detective, Elijah Baley, could solve the dark, baffling mystery.  Solaria demanded his help.

Baley didn't want to go.  But how could he refuse?

Earth's very existence was at stake.
</dc:description>

(...snip...)

**List of contents of the EPUB file (unzip -l):**

```
/DB001_F4/STACKS__Library$ unzip -l 'BOOK__SciFi__IAsimov__RDaneelOlivaw 2 - The Naked Sun__1956_1.epub'
Archive:  BOOK__SciFi__IAsimov__RDaneelOlivaw 2 - The Naked Sun__1956_1.epub
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
       20  2022-01-21 08:31   mimetype
        0  2023-07-27 20:01   META-INF/
      260  2023-07-05 20:03   META-INF/container.xml
        0  2023-08-06 22:09   OEBPS/
     7071  2023-08-06 22:09   OEBPS/content.opf
        0  2023-07-27 20:01   OEBPS/Fonts/
    30812  2019-12-02 20:35   OEBPS/Fonts/Aileron-BlackItalic.otf
    29904  2019-12-02 20:35   OEBPS/Fonts/Aileron-Black.otf
    30968  2019-12-02 20:35   OEBPS/Fonts/Aileron-BoldItalic.otf
    29196  2019-12-02 20:35   OEBPS/Fonts/Aileron-Bold.otf
    29612  2019-12-02 20:35   OEBPS/Fonts/Aileron-Italic.otf
    27644  2019-12-02 20:35   OEBPS/Fonts/Aileron-Regular.otf
   123408  2017-06-15 15:37   OEBPS/Fonts/Archivo-BoldItalic.ttf
   123072  2017-06-15 15:37   OEBPS/Fonts/Archivo-Bold.ttf
   117820  2017-06-15 15:38   OEBPS/Fonts/Archivo-Italic.ttf
   113644  2017-06-15 15:38   OEBPS/Fonts/Archivo-Regular.ttf
   100392  2015-06-04 16:56   OEBPS/Fonts/LiberationSerif-BoldItalic.ttf
   129416  2015-06-04 16:56   OEBPS/Fonts/LiberationSerif-Bold.ttf
   100420  2015-06-04 16:56   OEBPS/Fonts/LiberationSerif-Italic.ttf
   156076  2015-06-04 16:56   OEBPS/Fonts/LiberationSerif-Regular.ttf
        0  2023-08-06 17:43   OEBPS/Images/
   256154  2023-08-04 17:30   OEBPS/Images/BOOK__SciFi__IAsimov__RDaneelOlivaw 2 - The Naked Sun__1956__COVER.jpg
        0  2023-08-03 17:17   OEBPS/Styles/
    14715  2023-08-02 17:57   OEBPS/Styles/styling_fawcettcrest.css
     2898  2023-07-16 21:24   OEBPS/Styles/styling_fontfamilies.css
       58  2021-08-08 01:25   OEBPS/Styles/styling_paging.css
        0  2023-08-06 22:09   OEBPS/Text/
      676  2023-08-06 22:09   OEBPS/Text/binder_001_COVER.html
     1714  2023-08-06 22:09   OEBPS/Text/binder_002_DUSTJACKETBLURB.html
     9166  2023-08-06 22:09   OEBPS/Text/binder_003_STORYSUMMARY.html
     3272  2023-08-06 22:09   OEBPS/Text/binder_004_ABOUTAUTHOR.html
     1197  2023-08-06 22:09   OEBPS/Text/binder_005_TITLE.html
     2430  2023-08-06 22:09   OEBPS/Text/binder_006_COPYRIGHTS.html
      951  2023-08-06 22:09   OEBPS/Text/binder_007_DEDICATION.html
     3417  2023-08-06 22:09   OEBPS/Text/binder_008_CONTENTS.html
    32235  2023-08-06 22:09   OEBPS/Text/content_001.html
    30970  2023-08-06 22:09   OEBPS/Text/content_002.html
    30071  2023-08-06 22:09   OEBPS/Text/content_003.html
    22866  2023-08-06 22:09   OEBPS/Text/content_004.html
    23950  2023-08-06 22:09   OEBPS/Text/content_005.html
    31737  2023-08-06 22:09   OEBPS/Text/content_006.html
    27229  2023-08-06 22:09   OEBPS/Text/content_007.html
    28539  2023-08-06 22:09   OEBPS/Text/content_008.html
    22552  2023-08-06 22:09   OEBPS/Text/content_009.html
    28710  2023-08-06 22:09   OEBPS/Text/content_010.html
    28074  2023-08-06 22:09   OEBPS/Text/content_011.html
    31934  2023-08-06 22:09   OEBPS/Text/content_012.html
    24318  2023-08-06 22:09   OEBPS/Text/content_013.html
    24713  2023-08-06 22:09   OEBPS/Text/content_014.html
    32437  2023-08-06 22:09   OEBPS/Text/content_015.html
    26559  2023-08-06 22:09   OEBPS/Text/content_016.html
    29505  2023-08-06 22:09   OEBPS/Text/content_017.html
    35860  2023-08-06 22:09   OEBPS/Text/content_018.html
     4699  2023-08-06 22:09   OEBPS/toc.ncx
      196  2023-08-06 22:48   META-INF/calibre_bookmarks.txt
---------                     -------
  1978906                     57 files
/DB001_F4/STACKS__Library$
```

**Source code of Script 1:**

```
#!/bin/sh

#23456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+
####################################################################################################
###
### $Id: EPUB__CreateZipBundle.sh,v 1.3 2023/07/24 02:32:46 ericthered Exp ericthered $
###
### This script is used to create the well-formed BOOK EPUB file
### from the various files and sub-directories found within the WIP_Book directory.
###
### It is expected to be run from the '00__PUBLISH' directory.
###
### For further guidance, refer to the top-level script, 
###
###     EPUB__ExtractPdfToNormalizedText.sh
###
### for additional clarification of the expected process.
###
### KEYWORDS:   |PACKAGER|BOOK|HTML|EPUB|CSS|FONTS|IMAGES|
###
####################################################################################################


DBG=0

#BookWorkDirectory="WIP__Book"
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    case "${1}" in
        --bookWorkDirectory )
            BookWorkDirectory="${2}" ;
            shift ; shift ;
            ;;
        --sourceBase )
            SourceBase="${2}" ;
            shift ; shift ;
            ;;
        --debug )
            DBG=1 ; shift
            ;;
        * ) echo "\n\t Invalid parameter '${1}' used on command line.  Only valid options:  --bookDirectory {book_directory_name} \n Bye!\n" ; exit 1 ;
            ;;
    esac
done

if [ -z "${BookWorkDirectory}" ]
then
    echo "\n Must specify the work directory within which will be found \n the directory structure and files for creating the EPUB.\n Bye!\n"
    exit 1
fi

cd "${BookWorkDirectory}" || {
    echo "\n failed to set Book directory as working directory" ; exit 1
}

BookFiles=../`basename "$0" ".sh" `.bookfiles.txt

StartDir=`dirname "$0" `
Epub="${StartDir}/${SourceBase}.epub"


if [ ${DBG} -eq 1 ]
then
    echo "\t PWD = `pwd`"
    echo "\t [reporting from  $0 ]\n"
    ls -l
    exit 1
fi


find META-INF OEBPS -print | sort | 
    grep -v '^OEBPS/Fonts/DISABLED'         |
    grep -v '^OEBPS/Fonts/License__'        |
    grep -v '/HOLD/'                |
    grep -v '/HOLD$'                |
    grep -v '__HOLD$'               |
    grep -v '.css__'                |
    grep -v '^EPUB__splitChapters__FromMONOLITH.sh' |
    grep -v '^output.txt'               |
    awk -v sq="'" '{
        if( index( $0, " " ) > 0 ){
            printf("%s%s%s\n", sq, $0, sq ) ;
        }else{
            print $0 ;
        } ;
    }' >"${BookFiles}.tmp"
#   grep -v '^mimetype'             >"${BookFiles}.tmp"

{
    echo "mimetype"
    cat "${BookFiles}.tmp"
} >"${BookFiles}"

DBG=0

if [ ${DBG} -eq 1 ]
then
    cat "${BookFiles}"
    exit 1
fi


method_1()
{
    ###
    ### 2-Step method (only mimetype uncompressed)
    ###
    rm -fv "${Epub}" 2>&1 | awk '{ printf("\t %s\n", $0 ) ; }' >&2
    zip -X0 "${Epub}" mimetype

    ###  This form strips quotes around filenames
    #zip -9 "${Epub}" `cat "${BookFiles}.tmp" `

    awk -v zipcom="zip -9 \"${Epub}\"" 'BEGIN{
        printf("%s ", zipcom ) ;
    }{
        printf(" %s", $0 ) ;
    }END{
        printf("\n", $0 ) ;
    }' "${BookFiles}.tmp" >"${BookFiles}.job"

    . "./${BookFiles}.job"
    #if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    #then
    #   rm -f "./${BookFiles}.job"
    #fi

    echo "\t '${Epub}' created ...\n"
}


method_2()
{
    ###
    ### Single-Step method (all items uncompressed)
    ###
    rm -fv "${Epub}_2" 2>&1 | awk '{ printf("\t %s\n", $0 ) ; }' >&2

    ###  This form strips quotes around filenames
    #zip -X0 "${Epub}_2" `cat "${BookFiles}" `  

    awk -v zipcom="zip -X0 \"${Epub}_2\"" 'BEGIN{
        printf("%s ", zipcom ) ;
    }{
        printf(" %s", $0 ) ;
    }END{
        printf("\n", $0 ) ;
    }' "${BookFiles}" >"${BookFiles}.job"

    . "./${BookFiles}.job"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        rm -f "./${BookFiles}.job"
    fi

    echo "\t '${Epub}_2' created ...\n"
}


if [ ${DBG} -eq 1 ]
then
    echo "\t StartDir = '${StartDir}' ..."
    echo "\t     Epub = '${Epub}' ..."
    exit 1
fi


method_1
method_2

rm -f  "${BookFiles}"
rm -f  "${BookFiles}.tmp"
echo ""

if [ -f "${Epub}_2" ]
then
    ls -l "${Epub}" "${Epub}_2" 2>&1 | awk '{ printf("\t %s\n", $0 ) ; }' >&2
else
    ls -l "${Epub}" 2>&1 | awk '{ printf("\t %s\n", $0 ) ; }' >&2
fi
echo "\n Done!\n"
```

Comment: Does it crash other fm's, e.g., pcmanfm, dolphin, etc.?

Comment: Thank you for reviewing this, Dr Pippik.  I installed **nautilus**, but it did not crash when I selected the option to display properties.  I also installed **pcmanfm**, and it too has no crash when requesting the display of properties.

Comment: So... issue is in La Caja FM, not in your code.

Comment: I've compared the 5 EPUB documents I've generated so far.  I am of the opinion that the issue must be in the **content.opf** file.  By comparing the content.opf files, I am persuaded that Caja's possible issue is that it is unable to handle the **single-quote character if it is not paired-off** on any given line.  That seems to be the only pattern that I can come up with, suggesting a bug in some awk-based code (this is all pure guesswork on my part).  Any opinions on that?  As for the rest of that XML header, the same tags & poperties as used without causing crashes.

Comment: I am **worried** about converting more of my paperback SciFi books into EPUBs until I resolve this because, if it crashes while attempting to perform "Properties" assessment, what guarantees do I have that it would not "**break**" file evaluation/comparison during my **rsync** backup process !!!